# Jumping from screen A((Web Page) to Screen B(Web Page) bypassing intermediate screens(Web Pages) using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**This question is not about window handling** or juggling of multiple browser windows, its about navigating through web pages of a web application within same window.
I have a situation where

1.I navigate as screen A->Screen x->Screen Y-> Screen B

2.I need to capture certain parameters on screen B from First login

3.I need to verify those parameters on screen B from second login

Here what i wish to do is to avoid the non important task of navigating through intermediate screens & jump directly to the concerned screen. Or directly capture the concerned parameter without bothering about UI.

**Note- The URL on this application window is non editable manually.**

Example-

Login->Jump to Screen B(First Login)

Login->Jump to Screen B(Second Login)

Firsts of all, is it possible at all??
Please help me with the suggestions of how to achieve this

**Additional Detail**-

URL to view a project named **Selenium Test 275** (A specific web page in the application) is ->

```
http://172.24.186.71/esssfa/sfanew/UnitList.aspx?OID=12762&PID=12731&PRID=1&SecID=3
```

Comment: screen means you want to switch between diff. tabs of same browser?

Comment: no. Screen means page of web application ex- login page/Dashboard/Home

Comment: ohh then its easy that you can pass specific page URL and go into it when you want to get data.

Comment: I tried **driver.get(URL of desired page)** but it gave an invalid session page

Comment: please share your whole code.

Comment: Can u do that manually?

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh I do it all the time. However, it is unclear what you mean by "The URL on this application window is non editable manually."

Comment: You enter a URL on a parent window & enter,it opens another window on which all the action happens.Here on this browser window,one cannot alter the URL(its read only) manually. & when i tried altering the URL through selenium i.e. performed a **get** command from home page putting URL of concerned page trying to skip a couple of navigation steps, I got invalid session page

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

I think I understand what your asking now. If you want to easily jump back a few pages, to that spefic screen B, I would use JavaScript.

(-1) will get the last page that was on your browsers stack. (-2) two pages, and (2) will then make the browser get two pages forward on the browser. 
If you want to go back to Screen B try something like this after logging in.

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-2)")
```

Then a variable can be used to store the data from the last login that you want to compare.

Comment: Thanks for help eddie, **but i'm not trying to edit two different windows** . I'm trying to avoid unnecessary navigation between pages of a web app within the same window

Comment: The answer is useful(Thus 1+), But still not achieving my goal. I want to jump to specific screens using its URL, using **go(-2)** would land me on historic screen.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly that the second window opens based on response from the server? 
For e.g - the server could be returning a URI along with a session/security attribute(JSESSIONID, Authorization, etc) which is then appended with base URI to open up the new window. The session/security attribute explains the invalid session page message when you try to driver.get(URL) of the second page.

At the risk of being repetitive (rephrasing Vivek's question) - are you able to open the second screen in this way :
Login to the application (first screen) -> Open a fresh browser window -> Paste the (read-only) URL of the second screen and hit Enter -> Check second screen opens.

If yes, then it seems to be a case where it is not just simple GET request but possibly a request with some sort of Authorization code in the request headers.

Additional details might help answer your question : is it possible ?!

Comment: really? down vote ?! was someone expecting an answer with that vague problem description ? I was trying to offer pointers or where to look next !

Comment: I guess you are correct(Thus +1), but i would rather expect an answer to this problem.I've put up a sample URL to view a project in my question as additional detail,Let me know if you require anything else